# How to make button visible inside repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I have kept two button(`btnhide` and `btnunhide`) and a `label` inside the `repeater` and I have made button `btnunhide` invisible initially. Now what I want is that as I press button `btnhide` then `btnunhide` which is invisible intially  should be `visible`. 
Solution Will Be great help.

Html used

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
        <ItemTemplate> 

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>   
            <asp:Button ID="btn" CommandName="h" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnhide" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Unhide" />     

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "h")
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just a single button by changing the `Text` to hide/unhide and do the functionality as required by just checking the `Text` property of the `button`.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "h")
    {
        Button btn = (Button)(e.CommandSource);
        if(btn.Text == "hide")
        {
           btn.Text = "unhide";
           //Do additional work here, when unhiding.
        }
        else
        {
           btn.Text = "hide";
           //Do additional work here, when hiding.
        }

    }
}
```

I Hope, this helps. Thanks